# Return url functionality

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, request.querystring

I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC with C#.

I have a functionality on my Login controller to take a parameter called `ReturnUrl`. The Idea is, that if this is set when the user logs in then I can redirect them back to the page. Straight forward enough.

The code looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
{
     ...
}
```

However, the login functionality is handled by MVC and the main content is using Angular (version 1 not 2).  Routes in my app are (for example) `http://localhost/#/location1`.

If I hit my MVC login page with (again, just an example) `http://localhost/Login/?returnUrl=http://localhost/#/location1`, then all I get in my `returnUrl` parameter is `http://localhost/`. It drops anything from the # symbol onwards.

Any ideas how to stop the code automatically escaping at the # symbol and taking the full url as the `returnUrl` object?

Comment: Please don't use [tag:asp.net-mvc] for ASP.NET Core MVC related tags, it's [tag:asp.net-core-mvc]. [tag:asp.net-mvc] is for the legacy ASP.NET MVC webstack. Also don't put tags into question title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you notice in your browser's debug tools, the browser would not be sending this `#` and any text after it to the server, so the server wouldn't know about its existence at all.

So instead of something like below,

`http://localhost/Login/?returnUrl=http://localhost/#location1`

do this (note the encoding of `#` into `%23` in the url)

`http://localhost/Login/?returnUrl=http://localhost/%23location1`

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 ideas that might work for you:

1. try escaping the return url in the client vefore sending the request.
2. instead of string change the return url type to Uri object

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   [AllowAnonymous] 
   public IActionResult Login(Uri returnUrl = null)
   {
        ...
   }
   ```

Comment: I get a compilation error changing from string to Uri.  No control of the client url as it could be a bookmark from a page within our app unfortunately :-(